# Image not loading from directory where users upload images, no error generated

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have a simple Item page where users can create new items and upload an image for the associated with the Item. The images are stored in a folder named ItemImages and when displaying all the Items i need to retrieve the image from this folder based on the file reference stored in the databse.

for some reason It doesn't find the image and doesn't display it and no errors are generated, it doesn't even say 404 not found.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        var imagePath = item.ImagePath.ToString();


        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="~/ItemImages/dog.png" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) </h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Price:   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Date Listed:  @dateString</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

And my file structure :

[image]

Comment: The 404 response will also show you where it is looking for the image. How does it differ from what you expect? Incidentally, what are you going to do when someone uploads an image that has the same name as another?

Comment: variable imagePath is declared, but it is not used I guess. Instead dog.png in image src is used.

Comment: @KhurramIshaque I just put dog.png for simplicity and im testing with a png file i have in my ItemImages folder, but the image doesn't load

Comment: @Crowcoder The 404 response now shows up (it didn't before) it is looking for the image in http://localhost:50226/ItemImages/dog.png which seems to be the right path but it doesn't find it. And my files are named by a generated GUID so all file names are unique, I only put dog.png here for simplicity sake

Comment: `dog.png` gives you a 404? If you view source, what the `img` tag look like?

Comment: @mxmissile I can't see dog.png in source it just says 404 cannot find dog.png

Comment: Sorry I meant your view, the rendered html source. What does the `<img` tag look like?

Comment: <img class="card-img-top" src="/ItemImages/dog.png" alt="Card image cap"> @mxmissile

Comment: This happens when you run in Visual Studio? Or deployed to a server?

Comment: run locally from visual studio @mxmissile